# How do I interpret お釣りが来るほど？

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

[image]

> 豪邸を三つ作っても**お釣りが来るほど**の価値がある一級品の武器の筈だ。

I'm not sure how to interpret this part of the sentence. Is it some kind of phrase? I feel that it means something like "It should be a first class weapon that, even if you made three 豪邸, would be worth more."

Thank you!

Comment: Translation requests are per se off-topic. Can you give us your best guess first?

Comment: Dictionary definition of [お釣りが来る](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/31791/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8A%E9%87%A3%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8C%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that. It says that weapon is worth well more than three luxurious houses. That phrase is often used for a valuable. DanMachi?